# Issue in parsing float number in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Today I come across a very strange situation while getting value from dictionary.I have made two cases here.

**Case 1**

if I write code below

```
let str = "{\"num\":2}"

var dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)!

if let num = dict["num"] as? Float {
    print("Value is \(num)")
} else {
    print("parse error")
}

func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

As you can see value for key `num` is `Integer` but while fetching value from dictionary I expect value as `Float`. so it should go to else block but it prints the value.

**Case 2**

```
var test = 2
var dict:[String:Any] = [String:Any]()
dict["num"] = test
if let num = dict["num"] as? Float {
        print("Value is \(num)")
} else {
        print("parse error")
}
```

As I have not defined data type so by default it should be integer here & I expect value to be `Float`. This does work as I expect
Now here is does not print value it show the `parse error`

Please explain to me why this is happening ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is - dictionaries in those two cases are actually not identical.

In second case, the value of `dict["num"]` in of `Int` type, because you explicitly assigned an `Int` to it.

In first case however, you get a dictionary via `JSONSerialization` which turns numbers to `NSNumber` instances. So, the value of `dict["num"]` is of `NSNumber` type. And `NSNumber` initialized with an `Int` can be succesfuly cast to both `Int` and `Float`

Comment: Why these two Int are different. I guess we have only one data type as Int in swift which is of structure type.

Comment: Because those are not two Ints. The second one is Int, the first one is NSNumber (just initialized with Int)

Comment: But as I have added float check so why NSNumber is accepted and parse why not specifically Float

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're creating json and inserting into `dict` which is getting the value in `[String: Any]` format. Here `dict["num"]` is in `NSNumber` format.

In the second case you created the `dict` with `[String: Any]` format but put the value as `Int`. `var test = 2` this line makes variable `test` as Int and when you're inserting that value into `dict` with format `[String: Any]`, it's taking the value of format `Any` as `Int`.

So basically in second case, `dict["num"]` is `Int`.

[From Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310), variable will take the datatype of the value it was assigned at the beginning.

That's why you can convert Any to Float at the first case but cannot convert Int to Float at the second.

If you try with `var test: Float = 2`, you'll get the value at the second case also.

Comment: If first is Int then it should not work because I expect it to be Float. But lets say even if it is Any then why it works ? I just want it to be Float. If I wanted it to be Any then any datatype should have been worked.But I here I just want a Float nothing else. Please explain more & correct me if I am wrong

Comment: First is `Any` inside `dict`, which can be converted to `Float` by `as? Float`. But second case it's `Int`, to convert Int to Float you'll need to use `dict["num"] = Float(test)`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if let num = dict["num"] as? NSNumber {
       let floatValue = num.floatValue
        print("Value is \(floatValue)")
} else {
        print("parse error")
}
```